# Getting values from multiple lists to one in Red language

Tags: list, rebol, red

I want to get values from 2 series into one but it is not working:

I have 2 series:

```
a: [1 2 3]
b: [4 5 6 7]
```

I want to get all values in one list, so that I can access them as allv/1, allv/2... allv/7.

Following is not working since it makes a series of series and not series of values:

```
allv:  [a b]
print allv     ; => prints all 6 values, but following do not work: 
print allv/1   ; => gives a  (desired is 1)
print allv/2   ; => gives b  (desired is 2)
print allv/3   ; => gives none (desired is 3)
```

I tried following function to combine values in one series:

```
mycombine: function [ll][
    temp: []
    foreach l ll [
        repeat i length? l [
            temp: append temp l/:i ] ]
    temp]

mycombine [a b]
```

But above gives error:

```
*** Script Error: length? does not allow word! for its series argument
*** Where: length?
*** Stack: rncombine
```

The series has got converted into word and is not working.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append

```
a: [1 2 3]
b: [4 5 6 7]
c: [8 9 10]
d: [11 12 13 14]
>> allv: append a b
== [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
>> a
== [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

does what you want. But beware even a contains all values, as you have appendend the values of b to the block a. If you want a new block you have to use

```
allv: append copy a b
```

If you want to append more series you can do

```
>> foreach x [a b c d] [ append [] reduce x]
== [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14]
```

Instead of reduce also `get x` is working.
Another way of combining

```
>> compose [(a) (b) (c)]
== [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ]
```

Comment: I have variable number of series to be combined. What if I have to combine 4 series with different number of elements in each?

Comment: you can append as many times as you like, just take care to what block you append

Comment: I have combine a and b into another series, leaving a and b unchanged. That is important.

Comment: Then use a new block/series where you append to. see the last two examples above.

Comment: Is this different / not recommended / not needed: `allv: append copy allv copy a`

Comment: The second copy is superfluous and not recommended. The first copy would not work if allv is not introduced before as allv: [] . If it is defined before it is a new initializing of allv.